# Redirect to mobile page while scraping in R

Tags: r

I have been testing a web scrape in R for several weeks for the same site and have had no mobile website issues. This morning, after performing extremely light scraping (2 total web page hits), my third hit is now redirecting to a mobile version of the page. When I view the exact same URL in Internet Explorer 11 on the same IP address, I am direct to the full site, not the mobile site.

Another question on stackoverflow was asked similarly, and the answer was that the User Agent was likely the culprit in R. I have made my R session mimic my Internet Explorer session exactly with the following code:

```
options(HTTPUserAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko")
```

This, unfortunately, did not appear to fix the issue. Does anyone have any other guesses on how I may view the full site once again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, it appears that the XML and/or xml2 libraries do not pass the HTTPUserAgent option when sending header information to the website. By using the RCurl package, I was able to use getURLContent() instead of read_html() to navigate to the correct site because getURLContent() allows you to specify the HTTPUserAgent.

The website I am working with must have changed rules today to send unidentified users to the mobile version of their site, this workaround fixed my issue.

Comment: You can also use `GET(...)` in the `httr` package, which also lets you set the user_agent.

Comment: you can use `user_agent()` in `html_session()` in `rvest`, too